# Excel: apply non predetermined formulas to an automatically selected range

Tags: excel, range, finance, sumifs, subtotal

Basically I want to apply any formula using as input the cells from a range that follow a certain criteria.

So this might be the same as SUMIF, COUNTIF , or subtotals, only with any other formula.

Example: column 1 is project#, column 2 is cash flows, column 3 is year, and i want to have a column 5 showing for each project the XNPV or the XIRR.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: ... and yet you did not think that supplying an example of the range, an example of the criteria  or even a sample formula was important. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I m sorry Jeeped, it's my first post and I was just trying to be brief. Afyer your comment I made an example but I don t have reputation enough to upload it. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data in cols **A** and **B** and we want to apply a function in column **C** using that data.  Here is one example:

```
Sub formularizer()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, N As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    s1 = "SUM"
    s2 = "=" & s1 & "(A1,B1)"
    Range("C1").Formula = s2
    Range("C1").Copy Range("C2:C" & N)
End Sub
```

[image]